# How to register custom actions on messages

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I would like to allow a user to double tap or force touch a message bubble and handle an event, similar to the `didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath` method. Are custom event actions like this possible using `JSQMessagesViewController`? Because I have not seen anything in the documentation besides the `didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath` method I mentioned above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not as of current develop branch.

You can however add it yourself here:
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Views/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.m

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the framework, exactly how would I add custom actions? (P.s. Thanks for the response)

Comment: You edit JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.m yourself.
I would also recommend creating a pull request to the author.

Depending on your setup you may want to use your own fork of JSQMessagesViewController as a git submodule inside of your repo.

Comment: Yes I understand that but where in that file do I make my changes? It is also in Objective-C so I need to somehow figure that out as well

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/compare/develop...psineur:patch-1 You also will need to add new delegate methods in the protocol and implementations and forward them to your code